how to make sure the yocto esdk contains the template conf and meta layer in standalone installer?
I'm trying to build an esdk for yocto that can build any apps / images for my board. I'm building everything on docker.
However, I see that the esdk copies a hard coded path for the meta layer's templateconf directory. When I try to install it on native host linux, it creates an error
Error: TEMPLATECONF value points to nonexistent directory '/<docker_path_to_template_conf>'

How do I prevent this from happening and make sure my esdk is fully standalone ?
